# Org Shape - Not reflecting the apps from Prod Org

Tags: salesforcedx

We've enabled Orgshape(Beta) feature recently and tried to create the scratch based on our Prod org, but it is not showing up the custom apps and connected app type in the created scratch org.I was in an understanding that Org shape will mimic the prod org. Is that not the case? Can someone help to provide some suggestion on how to bring the missing apps in the scratch org?

Link we followed: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_scratch_orgs_shape.htm

Comment: https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000009TPk Post your query here.

Answer (score 2):

Org shape will mimic not the metadata but only your production ***settings, licenses, and feature***!

**Org snapshots** will also mimic metadata and data, this is in the pilot as of the winter 21 release!

Looks like what you are expecting not something that **Org Shape** will provide you and instead **Org Snapshot** will provide.

Here is a short overview of what features, settings and licenses are

**Features**

> features in the scratch org definition file provide the ability to specify additional add-on functionality that can be supported in the Edition but isn’t available out of the box. Features generally enable add-on licenses in the org and things that a user cannot enable themselves in the org via Setup

**Settings**

> settings in the scratch org definition file provide the ability to programmatically enable or disable Settings in the org. Settings in the org are generally found in “Settings” pages in the Setup UI — for instance “Email Settings” or “Notes Settings” — and are often (but not always) boolean checkboxes that allow you to turn on or off various capabilities available with the associated feature.

An example of this is discussed in this [blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/features-and-settings-and-scratch-orgs-oh-my.html)

**Licenses**

> A user license determines the baseline of features that the user can access. Every user must have exactly one user license. You assign user permissions for data access through a profile and optionally one or more permission sets.

> With Org Shape for Scratch Orgs, you can leave building the scratch org definition(`project-scratch-def.json`) to Salesforce. After you capture the org’s shape, you can spin up scratch orgs based on it. The metadata like apps and connected apps still need to be in your source control pulled from your org using Salesforce CLI.

Comment: Summary: It lets you automatically create your "scratch org configuration file" from an org. All metadata still needs to be in Unlocked Packages or a source metadata.

Comment: Like that! Let me add in to be clear!!

Answer (score 0):

Org Shape simply allows developers to bypass the need to create a Scratch Org Definition File, which can be very trial-and-error if you don't know what you're doing (my first experience had me create about 10 Scratch Orgs just to get our org's Scratch Org Definition File correct!).

All of your metadata will still need to be in a source format metadata folder, including apps, profiles, custom objects, and everything else. This feature simply saves you the step of repeatedly experimenting with a JSON file to get things just right, flipping on all the right settings for you so you can get started with DX development on Scratch Orgs.